# Facebook Like Button With "Large" Property Renders as Small on Mobile

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

So via the [Facebook Like Button Configurator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) I generated the code to use a large facebook Like button with a counter.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

While this works perfectly on my Desktop Browsers (Chrome/Firefox), when testing it on my mobile Samsung device (Chrome Mobile/Samsung Browser) the button renders as the regular small one, despite the code specifically set to ***data-size="large"***.

This is very frustrating, since the benefit of having a larger like button is all about mobile, not desktop (less precision required when tapping with your thumb on mobile).

Just to note, when testing via the Facebook Android App's web-view, it also renders correctly as the large variant. Only when accessing my website directly from mobile browsers does this problem occur.

I'm at a complete loss. Anyone have any clue as to why this is happening or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this had nothing to do with mobile, but rather with being logged into facebook or not. I just happen to not be logged into facebook on my mobile browsers at the time of testing.

Users who are not logged into facebook may see the old like button which didn't support the new "large" parameter. An official bug report and a response from facebook about this issue has been posted:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/120038005114426/

Apparently the new button is still in the process of being "rolled out" and so it is just a matter of time until this is resolved permanently.